# Xpages - Bean does not exist error

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib, xpages-ssjs

I am using Name picker provided by extension library. Since I need to retrieve names for active directory instead of names.nsf, I used beanNamePicker to get names from Active Directory. It is working fine, but sometime I am getting the below error. The error goes off if I refresh the database in designer. Any idea on how to avoid this error without refresh?

```
com.ibm.xsp.FacesExceptionEx: !BeanNamePickerData.Bean0doesnotexist!
!BeanNamePickerData.Bean0doesnotexist!
```

Domino Version : 8.5.3 UP1.

Answer (score 1):

Where in the NSF is the code for your bean, and which version of DDE 8.5.3 are you using? There were problems with the Java design element in early versions of 8.5.3 which caused this behaviour of making them fall out of the build path. I think they were fixed in FP3.

You can resolve the problem completely by using the latest version of Designer. You can still set the minimum supported release in xsp.properties to 8.5.3 with confidence that you're not accidentally using any new functionality.