# XPages - Bean does not exists error after code paste

Tags: jsf, xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I refreshed some java classes in my XPages app by pasting them from other db. After that I constanly getting error on any page:

```
com.ibm.xsp.FacesExceptionEx: Bean livescripts.core.ui.beans.BannerUtilLinksList does not exist
```

This bean is on AppLayout and works in other apps

```
<xe:this.bannerUtilityLinks>
    <xe:beanTreeNode loaded="true"
        nodeBean="livescripts.core.ui.beans.BannerUtilLinksList">
    </xe:beanTreeNode>
</xe:this.bannerUtilityLinks>
```

Full stack trace:

```
com.ibm.xsp.FacesExceptionEx: Bean livescripts.core.ui.beans.BannerUtilLinksList does not exist
at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.tree.complex.BeanTreeNode.getBeanInstance(BeanTreeNode.java:85)
at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.tree.complex.BeanTreeNode.getType(BeanTreeNode.java:157)
at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.tree.impl.TreeUtil$ListIterator.moveToNext(TreeUtil.java:93)
at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.tree.impl.TreeUtil$ListIterator.<init>(TreeUtil.java:63)
at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.tree.impl.TreeUtil.getIterator(TreeUtil.java:113)
at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.tree.impl.TreeImpl.iterateChildren(TreeImpl.java:60)
at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.tree.impl.AbstractTreeContext$NodeContextImpl.iterateChildren(AbstractTreeContext.java:83)
at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.renderkit.html_extended.outline.tree.AbstractTreeRenderer.renderChildren(AbstractTreeRenderer.java:218)
at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.renderkit.html_extended.outline.tree.AbstractTreeRenderer.render(AbstractTreeRenderer.java:195)
at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.renderkit.html_extended.outline.tree.AbstractTreeRenderer.render(AbstractTreeRenderer.java:185)
at com.ibm.xsp.theme.bootstrap.renderkit.html.extlib.layout.ResponsiveAppLayoutRenderer.writeBannerUtilityLinks(ResponsiveAppLayoutRenderer.java:404)
at com.ibm.xsp.theme.bootstrap.renderkit.html.extlib.layout.ResponsiveAppLayoutRenderer.writeBannerContent(ResponsiveAppLayoutRenderer.java:307)
at com.ibm.xsp.theme.bootstrap.renderkit.html.extlib.layout.ResponsiveAppLayoutRenderer.writeBanner(ResponsiveAppLayoutRenderer.java:271)
at com.ibm.xsp.theme.bootstrap.renderkit.html.extlib.layout.ResponsiveAppLayoutRenderer.writeMainFrame(ResponsiveAppLayoutRenderer.java:166)
at com.ibm.xsp.theme.bootstrap.renderkit.html.extlib.layout.ResponsiveAppLayoutRenderer.encodeBegin(ResponsiveAppLayoutRenderer.java:1028)
at com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeBegin(ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.java:146)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:956)
at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.layout.UIVarPublisherBase.encodeBegin(UIVarPublisherBase.java:112)
at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:842)
at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:853)
at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:853)
at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:853)
at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:853)
at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx._renderView(UIViewRootEx.java:1317)
at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.renderView(UIViewRootEx.java:1255)
at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.doRender(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:651)
at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl._renderView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:321)
at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:336)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:103)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:210)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:120)
at com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.render(FacesControllerImpl.java:270)
at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.renderFacesPage(FacesServlet.java:606)
at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.renderErrorPage(FacesServlet.java:501)
at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:183)
at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:138)
at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:576)
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1335)
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:853)
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:796)
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:565)
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1319)
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:662)
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:482)
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:357)
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:313)
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)
```

DDE Version: Release 9.0.1FP2 SHF63. What I've already tried:

1. Delete and copy-paste code again
2. Rename/Move class
3. Add it to faces-config as ManagedBean (here I get ClassNotFoundException)
4. Of cource, Clean/Rebuild project

Comment: Is class BannerUtilLinksList defined in Code/Java and has this class a public constructor without parameters?

Comment: In case class is not defined in Code/Java make sure folder is marked as "Source folder" (= added to Build Path)

Comment: @KnutHerrmann , Yes, it is defined in Code/Java. It doesn't have public constructor, but is't superclass does (I even added constractor to BannerUtilLinksList - no effect). Code/Java is in Java Build Path. This class works exellent in other app. Nothing changed when copied.

Comment: Problem seems similar to this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21573260/xpages-bean-does-not-exist-error) - looks like class falls out from build path...

Comment: Do you have 8.5.3 < FP3 ?

Comment: @KnutHerrmann , no, Release 9.0.1FP2 SHF63, that's why upgrade is not the way...

Comment: Does it work if you copy class into new folder `src` in PackageExplorer and mark `src` as "Source Folder"?

Comment: @KnutHerrmann, it's my fault. I upgraded some other classes, checked custom controls, etc. But forgot to update faces-cofig. Still such an error is too strange, because BannerUtilLinksList is not is faces-cofig. Thank you for help anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded some other classes, checked custom controls, etc. But forgot to update faces-config. Still such an error is too strange, because BannerUtilLinksList class is not is faces-config.